# How to save the result of an sql query to a variable in lazarus?

Tags: pascal, lazarus

I'm doing a project and i want to save a integer, that is read from a sql query.
How can i do this?
This is the query:

```
SELECT IDEmp
FROM Employee
Where IDLocal = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It requires a database dependent connection component. Since you don't specify the database you use, I'll assume sqlite in the (untested) example below.

```
{$mode delphi}
uses   Classes, SysUtils, strutils,sqlite3conn, sqldb, db;

function CreateQuery(pConnection: Tsqlconnection; pTransaction: TSQLTransaction): TSQLQuery;
begin
  result := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
  result.Database := pConnection;
  result.Transaction := pTransaction
end;

const rootfs = '/mnt/ext1/';

var
  connect: TSQLite3Connection;
  SQLQuery1: TSQLQuery;
  transact: TSQLTransaction;
  Query        : TSQLQuery;
  fn  : string;
begin
  connect:=TSQLite3Connection.create(nil);
  connect.LoginPrompt := False;
  connect.DatabaseName := 'D:\testing\touch2db\books.db';
  connect.KeepConnection := False;
  transact:=TSQLTransaction.create(nil);
  transact.action:=caNone;
  transact.database:=connect;
  connect.Transaction:=transact;
  Query := CreateQuery(Connect, Transact);
  Query.SQL.Text:='SELECT IDEmp FROM Employee Where IDLocal =:myidlocal'); 
  Query.Params.ParamByName('myidlocal').AsInteger:=1;
  Connect.Open;
  Query.Open;
  if Query.EOF then
      writeln('No Result!')
  else
    begin
      MyGoodInteger:=Query.FieldByName['IDEmp'].AsInteger;
      writeln('result = ',MyGoodInteger);
    end;
  Connect.Close;
  Query.Free;
  Transact.Free;
  Connect.Free;
end.
```

You'll find more example projects in your lazarus/examples/database folder.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft sql server. And in  lazarus IDE i'm using SQLdb and Data Acess. I'm trying to save the result but I can't do it

Comment: Well you need the freetds driver then to access sql server. But I have no practical experience with it, search/ask on the lazarus forum.